# Replace WebApplicationFactory service with mock for single integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to run an integration test. I'm using xUnit.

I created a standard `WebApplicationFactory` as a class fixture:

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class {

  protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
    Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseAutofac()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x => x.UseStartup<Startup>().UseTestServer());

  protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) =>
    builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
      //...can customize services here, FOR ALL tests
    });

}
```

And my test class:

```cs
public class FooTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>> {

  public FooTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory) => _factory = factory;
  private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

  [Fact]
  public void My_Test() {
    var myService = _factory.Services.GetService<IMyService>();
    //.....
  }

}
```

Suppose I want to replace a service in my container, with a mock. If I do that in the above custom `WebApplicationFactory` then it would be applicable to all tests. *But I want it for a specific test only.* The standard answer is to use `WithWebHostBuilder`:

```cs
var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => {
  builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
    services.Remove(services.Single(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IMyService)));  // remove service
    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyMockedService>();                           // add mock
  });
}).CreateClient();
```

But the result is an `HTTPClient`. *I don't need a client* - I need to test something to do with my server's configuration. So unless I misunderstand how the above works, I don't believe it applies to my use case.

So, for a single integration test, how can I replace a service with a mock?

Comment: I think it makes the most sense to just create another factory with the service replaced, as it makes it clear what the purpose of the class is. Otherwise, what I've previously done is to have a list of Mocks to replace services, and only replace the actual services when a Mock instance was provided

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks, you're probably right. Though I didn't understand this bit: "have a list of Mocks to replace services, and only replace the actual services when a Mock instance was provided". Any code you could maybe point to?

Comment: I cannot point to any link, as the implementation was entirely made by myself. The main difference is that I was using NUnit and using the Factory as a private implementation detail of a `BaseTest` class, so I could configure it as I wished at the unit test class level. I had a `BusinessServicesMocks` class with a number of `public Mock<ISomeService> SomeServiceMock { get; set; }` which I decided whether to instantiate and add mock calls or not according to each unit test. I didn't get to publish it anywhere, but I could write a blog post about it if you'd like (see website in profile)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No please don't trouble yourself. That's enough info to give me some ideas, thank you!

Comment: Great, shoot if you have more questions :)

Comment: Hey, I completely forgot to let you know and it's probably a bit late already, but, I ended up writing the post some time ago, you can find it on my site (link in profile)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Awesome, I'll read it and see if I can improve my code! Thanks.